# Como conseguir este efeito em uma barra de progresso?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Como fazer este efeito no texto dentro da barra de progresso em que o texto muda de cor de acordo com preenchimento da barra, e quando a barra alcança o texto, somente uma parte do texto muda de cor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que quando está em **50%** metade da cor do texto fica branca em contraste com o fundo preto e a outra metade preta em contraste com o fundo branco. Quando o fundo abaixo do texto for branco, o texto é totalmente preto e vice-versa.

Como fazer isso usando CSS e JavaScript para a barra ir de 0% a 100% num determinado período de tempo, digamos, em 10 segundos?

O código da barra seria este abaixo, mas pode se alterado à vontade para que se possa conseguir o efeito desejado:

```css
#barra{
    display: block;
    width: 298px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

#progresso{
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="barra">
   <div id="progresso">
   </div>
   <strong>15%</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Relacionada no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981763/1452488

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz apenas com CSS, deixei a animação com 5 segundos, mas os @keyframes eu dividi em 10 passos caso vc quera controlar melhor a animação com o JS.

*Deixei a animação com looping infinito, mas deixei um comment no css caso vc queira fazer ela parar quando completa 100%*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
h2{
    margin-left: 150px;
  }

.holder {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px; 
    background: white; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    color: #000;
    margin: auto;
}
.mask {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 10; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 0%; 
    background-color: red; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    color: #FFF;
    animation: load 5s linear infinite;
    /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; descomente se quiser que ela pare quando completar  (remova o "infinite" do animation acima)*/
}
@keyframes load {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    10% {
        width: 10%;
    }
    20% {
        width: 20%;
    }
    30% {
        width: 30%;
    }
    40% {
        width: 40%;
    }
    50% {
        width: 50%;
    }
    60% {
        width: 60%;
    }
    70% {
        width: 70%;
    }
    80% {
        width: 80%;
    }
    90% {
        width: 90%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="mask">
        <h2>100%</h2>
    </div>
    <h2>100%</h2>
</div>
```

Aqui tem um artigo do Google em português ensinando a controlar a Animação com JavaScript: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/css-vs-javascript?hl=pt-br

Ótimo artigo de animação com js em inglês: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Comment: Ficou legal....

Comment: @dvd Não tão sofisticado quanto o seu, mas quebra o galho rss. Como eu não sei muito de JS costumo tentar fazer tudo sempre com CSS primeiro, abs

Answer (score 3):

Consegui usando [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) (usei [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) também, que está defasado, mas para dar suporte a navegadores mais antigos) e criando duas camadas onde o texto da porcentagem é exibido (`<strong>`). À medida que a barra de progresso cresce, vai `clipando` a camada (`div`) onde o texto é preto, *revelando* o texto branco que é uma camada abaixo. Coloquei o código todo comentado para facilitar o entendimento. Se alguém tiver uma forma melhor ou diferente, é bem-vida.

Fiz um exemplo com uma barra menor para que se possa visualizar melhor:

```js
function ini(){
         $("input").remove(); // apenas para excluir o botão de iniciar :P
   var tempo = 10; // tempo em segundos
   var barra_width = $("#barra").width(); // pego a largura da barra, sem a borda
   var barra_height = $("#barra").height(); // pego a altura da barra, sem a borda
   var progresso_px = barra_width/tempo; // quantos pixels a barra será incrementada pelo tempo
   var progresso_text = $("#barra strong"); // pego as strongs com as porcentagens
   var progresso_div = $("#progresso"); // pego a div do progresso
   
   var temporizador = setInterval(function(){ // crio um temporizador para trabalhar a cada 1 segundo

      var incremento = progresso_div.width()+progresso_px; // calculo o quanto em pixels deverá ser incrementado na largura do progresso
      progresso_div.css("width",incremento+"px");

      if(progresso_div.width() <= barra_width-progresso_px){ // enquanto a barra for menor ou igual ao contêiner menos 1 incremento
         var porcentagem = Math.ceil((progresso_div.width()*100)/barra_width); // calculo a porcentagem, arrendondando pra cima
         progresso_text.text(porcentagem+"%"); // aplico a porcentagem aos strongs
      }else{
         progresso_div.css("width","100%"); // aplico 100% à largura do progresso
         progresso_text.text("100%"); // seto 100% ao texto das strongs
         clearInterval(temporizador); // apagado o temporizador
         console.log("fim!"); // exibe no console a mensagem de que terminou
      }
      
      var barra_strong1 = $("#barra strong:eq(1)"); // pego a primeira strong, que é onde o texto é branco
      // recorto a barra onde o texto é preto, da esquerda para a direita,
      // acompanhando a porcentagem
      // "clip" para navegadores não compatíveis com clip-path
      barra_strong1.css({
          "clip":"rect(0px "+barra_width+"px "+barra_height+"px "+incremento+"px)",
          "clip-path":"inset(0 0 0 "+porcentagem+"%)",
          "-webkit-clip-path":"inset(0 0 0 "+porcentagem+"%)"
      });
   }, 1000);

}
```

```css
#barra{
   display: block;
   width: 120px;
   height: 28px;
   color: #000;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   position: relative;
}

#progresso{
   display: block;
   background: #000;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

/* aqui eu seto a cor branca para o primeiro strong*/
#barra *:nth-child(2){
   color: #fff;
}

#barra strong{
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="barra">
   <div id="progresso"></div>
   <strong>0%</strong>
   <strong>0%</strong>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Iniciar" onclick="ini()" />
```

Answer (score -3):

ola, ótimas soluções.
1- imaginemos um número à buscar desconhecido (78),inicialmente a barra toda preenchida,  numero inicial (50), então a barra ficaria pintada entre 50-100, numa segunda tentativa (90), então ficaria pintado entre 50-90, assim sucessivamente até digitar 78.
2- e conforme esta diferença fosse ficando menor , iria mudando de cor, tipo 100 vermelho, 50 amarelo, 10 verde, e ao acertar preto
obrigado pela atenção